# По нажатию на "меню" исполняется второе условие и игнорируется первое, при повторном нажатии в обратном порядке. Необходимо одновременное исполнение

Tags: javascript, css3, веб-программирование

```
menu.onclick = function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("menu_wrap");
  if (x.className === "navigation-advertisement") {
    x.className += " wrap";
  } else {
    x.className = "navigation-advertisement";
  }
};
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятный, можете прояснить что именно срабатывает и при каких условиях?

Comment: При клике на меню должен прибавиться класс responsive к topnav, а по второму условию класс wrap к navigation-advertisement одновременно, но при клике на меню срабатывает условие f (x.className === "navigation-advertisement") и игнорируется певое. при повторном клике if (x.className === "topnav") {
  Необходимо чтобы при одном нажатии сработали оба

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так тут тогда все предельно ясно :) Дело в том что, вы проверяете как string ровняется ли ваш класс какому-то значению, но это и не правильно, вообще у классов есть свои методы. Надо проверять через `classList.contains`. Давай сократим твой код и сделаем правильным ;)

```js
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

menu.onclick = function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav"),
            y = document.getElementById("menu_wrap");
    var isContainX = x.classList.contains('responsive'),
            isContainY = y.classList.contains('wrap');
    isContainX ? x.classList.remove('responsive') : x.classList.add('responsive');
    isContainY ? y.classList.remove('wrap') : y.classList.add('wrap');
};
```

```css
.responsive {
  color: red;
}

.wrap {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
<div id="myTopnav" class="topnav ">Nav</div>
<div id="menu_wrap" class='navigation-advertisement'>menu_wrap</div>
```

Comment: Сагол гага. Все работатет как надо. Спасибо!

Comment: Рад помочь, удачи :)

Comment: Можешь выделить как правильный, вдруг кому-то понадобится ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно "myTopnav" и "menu_wrap" на одном элементе.

Ничего не игнорируется.

Попробуйте разнести по разным элементам (не сильно красиво, но самое простое)

Comment: спасибо вопрос решен.

Comment: можно принять ответ галкой

Comment: уже, ранее отметил.